# PHP login system won't header, and at relog must refresh to fully logout.

Tags: php, html, mysql

I know that there are many, many questions about my problem, I read much of them, but I can't find a solution of my problem, that's why I'm asking too.

I will write why do I think that I have the issues, and how to fix them, and I ask you to correct me if I'm wrong and help me with the solution, thank you. I've read a lot of information and topics from yesterday and still didn't found solutions.

I have 3 errors.

If I login with username "John" and then logout, and connect with username "Bob" it shows "John's" statistics.

When pressed login, page refreshes, it logs the user, but it won't redirect him via header on profile.php page.

Errors:

```
session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/vestiged/public_html/game/ucp/profile.php:1) in /home/vestiged/public_html/game/ucp/profile.php on line 3

PHP Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/vestiged/public_html/game/ucp/index.php:1) in /home/vestiged/public_html/game/ucp/index.php on line 19
```

I think that the first error is caused by cache that I have on my index.php (which is the login)

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

Second error, maybe because of form? I don't know!

I read about fixing error number 3, but I didn't find white spaces before .
Redirect with html meta tag works.

About Error 1 and Error 2, I don't have any CLUE about resolving them, and I'm searching answers and doing modifications in my script since yesterday and still couldn't fix it.

I am using old mysql, deprecated mysql, because I need only a presentation page.

I'm using login script into index.php, so you login from index.php.

Live DEMO if you want: https://vestigedayz.com/game/ucp 
Username: Username and Password: parola

https://vestigedayz.com/game/ucp/profile.php (you can acces it manually after login, because it won't redirect)

My code:

```
<?php
require('config.php');
session_start();
ob_start();
// If form submitted, insert values into the database.
if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $username = stripslashes($username);
  $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
  $password = stripslashes($password);
  $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
  //Checking is user existing in the database or not
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and password='".sha1($password)."'";
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
  if ($rows == 1) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header("Location: https://vestigedayz.com/game/ucp/profile.php"); 
    // Redirect user to index.php
  } else {
    echo "   <div class='hero'>
      <h1 id='title-1'>Parola greșită. :( <br>
     Încerci din nou?
     <br> <a href='index.php' style='color:white'> Click </a></h1> 
     </div>";
  }
} else {
}
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <!--Audio player-->
      <audio autoplay loop>
          <source src="audio/audio9.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
          <source src="audio/audio9.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
          Browserul tău nu suportă HTML5.
      </audio>   
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Vestige DayZ</title>
<meta property="og:url" content="https://vestigedayz.com/index.html" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Vestige DayZ" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Vestige DayZ" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://i.imgur.com/KHo2frf.png" />
<meta name="description" content="Vestige DayZ" />
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow,all" />
<meta name="keywords" content="SA:MP Vestige Day Z" />
<meta name="author" content="Vestige DayZ" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="img/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="img/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="img/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="img/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="img/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="img/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="img/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="img/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="img/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/android-chrome-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="manifest" href="img/manifest.json">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">


<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="img/mstile-144x144.png">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animsition.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/grid.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/overlay.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.1/animate.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
  <style>
      /* NOTE: The styles were added inline because Prefixfree needs access to your styles and they must be inlined if they are on local disk! */
      @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
.btn { display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1; padding: 4px 10px 4px; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; color: #333333; text-align: center;text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); vertical-align: middle; background-color: #f5f5f5; background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#e6e6e6)); background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); background-repeat: repeat-x; filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffffff, endColorstr=#e6e6e6, GradientType=0); border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6; border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); border: 1px solid #e6e6e6; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); cursor: pointer; *margin-left: .3em; }
.btn:hover, .btn:active, .btn.active, .btn.disabled, .btn[disabled] { background-color: #e6e6e6; }
.btn-large { padding: 9px 14px; font-size: 15px; line-height: normal; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; }
.btn:hover { color: #333333; text-decoration: none; background-color: #e6e6e6; background-position: 0 -15px; -webkit-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; -moz-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; -ms-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; -o-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; transition: background-position 0.1s linear; }
.btn-primary, .btn-primary:hover { text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); color: #ffffff; }
.btn-primary.active { color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); }
.btn-primary { background-color: #4a77d4; background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#6eb6de), to(#4a77d4)); background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); background-image: linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); background-repeat: repeat-x; filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#6eb6de, endColorstr=#4a77d4, GradientType=0);  border: 1px solid #3762bc; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active, .btn-primary.disabled, .btn-primary[disabled] { filter: none; background-color: #4a77d4; }
.btn-block { width: 100%; display:block; }

* { -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; -ms-box-sizing:border-box; -o-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box; }
html { width: 100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden; }
body { 
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background: #092756;
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%),-moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%, rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%, #092756 100%);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), linear-gradient(135deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3E1D6D', endColorstr='#092756',GradientType=1 );
}
.login { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 75%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -150px 0 0 -150px;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
.login h1 { color: #fff; text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); letter-spacing:1px; text-align:center; }

input { 
    width: 100%; 
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 45px rgba(100,100,100,0.2), 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
    -o-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
    transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
}
input:focus { box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 45px rgba(100,100,100,0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2); }

    </style>


        <script src="js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="animsition-overlay">
  <div id="section-1">
    <header class="main_h">
      <div class="menufix"> <a class="logo" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo-sample.png" alt="Hello"></a>
        <div class="mobile-toggle"> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span> </div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="out active animsition-link" href="index.html">ACASA</a></li>
            <li class="line"><a class="out animsition-link" href="aboutproject.html">DESPRE PROIECT</a></li>
            <li class="line"><a class="out animsition-link" href="gallery.html">GALERIE</a></li>
            <li class="line"><a class="out animsition-link" href="forum">FORUM</a></li>
            <li class="line"><a class="out animsition-link" href="UCP">UCP</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <!-- / row --> 

    </header>
    <div class="hero">
      <h1 id="title-1">SA:MP DayZ<em><span>V</span>ESTIGE</em>Loghează-te la caracterul tău.</h1>


       <body>
    <div class="login">
<form action="https://vestigedayz.com/game/ucp/index.php" method="post" name="login">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
</div>


  <!-- END #section-1 -->

    <p class="dolje">&nbsp;<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script> &nbsp;www.vestigedayz.com- All rights Reserved.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- END #section-credits --> 
</div>
<!-- END .animsition-overla --> 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.matchHeight-min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/animsition.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.parallax-scroll.js"></script> 
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.cbpQTRotator.min.js"></script> 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#owl-partners").owlCarousel({

          autoPlay: 4000, 
          stopOnHover : true,
          pagination : false,
          items : 5,
          itemsDesktop : [1199,4],
          itemsDesktopSmall : [959,3]     
      });     
    });
</script> 
<script>
    $( function() {
    $( '#cbp-qtrotator' ).cbpQTRotator();                   
    });
</script> 
<script src="js/functions.js"></script> 
<script src="js/particle.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-15815880-3']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'https://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

logout.php

```
<?php 

include("config.php"); //including our config.php 
session_start(); //starting session 
session_destroy(); //destroying it 
header('location: https://vestigedayz.com/game/ucp/'); //redirecting user to index.php 

?>
```

Part of profile.php

```
<?php
include("config.php"); //including our config.php 
session_start(); //starting session 
error_reporting(0); 

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) 
{ 
    $username = $_SESSION['username']; //setting variable username as one from session 
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");  //selecting all from table users where username is name that your is loged in;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) //looping thousgt table to get informations 
    {
```

Comment: In `profile.php`, there's an invalid char `/` after `if(isset($_SESSION['username']))`. Also in the same file, the `if` block should end with `}` instead of with '{'. These might be unrelated to the errors you are getting, but need to be removed nonetheless.

Comment: @pgngp  yeah there was additional text //text.   And it's part of profile.php, the original script it's too long to be read.

Comment: Do you have any white space after the closing ?> tag in config.php? If so, remove it

Comment: I don't have in neither of .php scripts @Chris

Comment: I don't have in neither of .php scripts @Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I login with username "John" and then logout, and connect with username "Bob" it shows "John's" statistics.

That's a [session fixation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation) issue. Clearly `session_destroy()` in logout.php is not working. While you should *always* change the session id whenever there is a change to authentication (login and logout) that's not going to fix the problem here. Presumably logout.php is emitting the "headers already sent" error. (see below).

> Cannot send session cache limiter

**DO NOT TRY TO MAKE YOUR SESSION PAGES CACHEABLE**

This is really difficult to get right and should not be attempted until you are an expert with PHP programming (and even then it is very dubious).

This is *not* caused by the META headers you've shown us. It's in your [PHP config](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php).

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
```

This is nonsense. Remove it.

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

This is ambiguous. Remove it.

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Go and read those docs again. Looking at the error, in your case it's most likely a BOM on the file, but the way you write your code invites failures - don't use a closing tag unless you really need to. Use a better editor or find out how to configure the one you are using to save files as ascii or utf8 without a BOM.

> sha1($password)

This is insecure - you're not using a salt.