# PHP fetch page shows blank

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Why my page is blank? Wrong code? I can't see what is wrong here

Errors shown: 
 Call to a member function prepare() on null in on line 28

line 28 is the $query.  Because I selected "edit" and didn't use it or why is shown this error and page blank?

thank you. On what I've read, I didn't find any solution, I used mysql_* until now, so I moved on better code, thank you for your time.

index.PHP

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Vestige DayZ | BanList</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->  
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icons/favicon.ico"/>
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animate/animate.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/util.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php  
        include_once 'config.php';

        $query = $config -> prepare("SELECT `edit`, `user_banned`, `ban_reason`, `ban_time`, `user_banner`, `ban_timestamp` FROM `samp_ban` ORDER BY `edit` ASC LIMIT 10");  
        if($query -> execute())  
        {  
            $query_results = $query->fetchAll();

        }  
    ?>

        <div class="limiter">
            <div class="container-table100">
                <div class="wrap-table100">
                        <div class="table">

                            <div class="row header">


                                <div class="cell">
                                    Utilizator
                                </div>
                                <div class="cell">
                                    Motiv
                                </div>
                                <div class="cell">
                                    Perioada
                                </div>
                                <div class="cell">
                                    Oferit de catre
                                </div>
                                <div class="cell">
                                    Data:
                                </div>
                            </div>

                                        <?php foreach( $query_results as $query_result ) { 
                                        if($query_result["ban_time"] == 0) { $query_result["ban_time"] = "Permanent"; } ?>

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="cell" data-title="Full Name">
                            <?php echo $query_result["user_banned"]; ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cell" data-title="Full Name">
                            <?php echo $query_result["ban_reason"]; ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cell" data-title="Full Name">
                            <?php echo $query_result["ban_time"]; ?> 
                        </div>
                         <div class="cell" data-title="Full Name">
                            <?php echo $query_result["user_banner"];  ?>
                        </div>
                         <div class="cell" data-title="Age">
                            <?php echo $query_result["ban_timestamp"];  ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>

                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




    <!--===============================================================================================-->  
        <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
        <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/popper.js"></script>
        <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
        <script src="vendor/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

config

```
  <?php 
        $database_host = "localhost"; 
        $database_user = "sure"; 
        $database_pass = "abcd"; 
        $database_db = "aaa"; 

        $config = new PDO("mysql:host=$database_host;dbname=$database_db;charset=utf8", $database_user, $database_pass); 
        $config -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    ?>
```

Comment: It means that `$config` is not defined. You do use it, so it should be.

Comment: can you post your config.php file without your credentials?

Comment: Done @UmarKhan..

Comment: have you modified the `include_path` at all? Is the `config.php` script in the same directory as the current page?

Comment: Yes @RamRaider.  config.php is in the same directory as index.php.   (But I have another config.php in another directory, is that a problem?)

Comment: the connection script looks OK so it could be that the file is not being included at all - add some sort of debug statement that you can see to it - ie: `exit('ok');`  I don't think a similar named file in another directory would cause this unless the `include_path` is pointing to a different location - use `get_include_path()` to check or `get_included_files()`

Comment: Unrelated to your current problem, but why call this 'config'? Isn't `$config` a `$databaseConnection` and does `config.php` not `connectToDatabase.php`? Don't be afraid to use real descriptive names, and I think you should try to avoid abbreviations (= my opinion).

Comment: does the `edit` column indeed exist?

Comment: Code works fine on xampp localhost D:\xampp\php\PEAR
But on webhost it shows blank.  and path: .:/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/share/pear

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner post it as correct answer so i can vote it, thank you.  I have another fast question, if i have a mysql_* login system, it is hard to rewrite on mysqli_*  or in PDO?

Comment: looks like the include path has been set so use `include __DIR__ . '/config.php';` perhaps

Comment: edit column didn't exist, I forgot to "Edit" it in my correct column.   @romraider  i have another question here, if you can help me.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49342519/php-login-system-wont-header-and-at-relog-must-refresh-to-fully-logout